# Use full ethereum balance for token transaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, tokens, balances, gas-price

I want to use whatever ethereum is available in my account as transaction fee to send a token transaction. I know the gas I need, so in theory I thought the following formula would work:

```
gasPrice = balanceInWei / gas
```

so I tried with 0.001 ETH:

```
gasPrice = 1000000000000000 Wei / 130091
```

which results in 0.000000007686926843 ETH per gas unit

But I got

> Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

I am sending no value, so in theory the gas * price do match the funds.

What am I missing? Do I have to use a minimum of 1 gwei as gas?

I am using Web3js version 5.6.0. Here's the code:

```
function main() {
    console.log('Transferring from address 0x8..');
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SOURCE_WALLET_ADDRESS).then(function (nonce) {
        console.log('The nonce is ' + nonce);
        web3.eth.getBalance(SOURCE_WALLET_ADDRESS).then(function (balance) { 

            console.log('Balance ' + balance); 
            sendTransaction(nonce, balance);
        });
    });
}

function sendTransaction (nonce, balance) {
    var tokensToSend = '1000';
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, CONTRACT_ADDRESS, { from: SOURCE_WALLET_ADDRESS });
    var balanceInWei = balance * 1000000000000000000;
    var gas = 130091;

    // Find out gas price to use full eth balance
    gasPrice = balanceInWei / gas;

    console.log('\r\nStarting transaction. with nonce ' + nonce);
    console.log('Gas price : ' + gasPrice + '\r\n');

    let details = {
        "to": CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        "from": SOURCE_WALLET_ADDRESS,
        "data": contract.methods.transfer(DESTINATION_WALLET_ADDRESS, tokensToSend).encodeABI(),
        "value": web3.utils.toHex(tokensToSend),
        "nonce": nonce,
        "gas": gas, // tx fee (gas * gasPrice)
        "gasPrice": gasPrice, // has to be in Wei
        "chainId": 1 // EIP 155 chainId - mainnet: 1, rinkeby: 4
    }

    const transaction = new EthereumTx(details);
    transaction.sign(Buffer.from(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex'));
    const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')).then(function (transId) {
        console.log('My job here is done. ' + transId.transactionHash);
    });
}

main();
```

Example output:

```
*** PROGRAM START ***

Transferring from address 0x8Df3..
The nonce is 71
Balance: 0.003703316

Starting transaction. with nonce 71
Gas price : 28467119170.426853
```

Comment: Which wallet do you use? I mean the one where the error happens.

Comment: I am using web3js, so no wallet involved, not sure what you mean

Comment: Can you share the exact code you ran to make the transaction?

Comment: of course @smarx -- I've updated the question with the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code multiplies the balance passed in by `10**18`, presumably to convert from ether to wei. But the balance is coming from `web3.eth.getBalance`, which **returns wei already**. So you're setting the gas price way too high (by a factor of `10**18`). Just use:

```
var balanceInWei = balance;
```

(Or use `balance` directly.)

**EDIT**

You should also avoid trying to use a gas price with fractions of wei, so floor the result of the division:

```
gasPrice = Math.floor(balanceInWei / gas);
```

**EDIT 2**

This line tries to send the same amount of ether as you're sending tokens. You said you're not trying to transfer any ether, so delete this line:

```
"value": web3.utils.toHex(tokensToSend),
```

Comment: When I see the output of the balance after its retrieved, the amount is shown in eth - I have updated the question with an output example

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the formula is correct. The error must be in how things are handled in the code - perhaps var types or something

Comment: I've seen that people like to use hex values in all fields of the transaction, not sure if could be for things like this

Comment: `web3.eth.getBalance` returns the balance in wei. Can you share the code that produces the output you added to the question? (The current code produces no such output.)

Comment: its the same code, I just removed the logging. let me fix it

Comment: Also please include the version of web3.js that you're using.

Comment: "Web3js version 5.6.0" doesn't exist. The current production version of web3.js is 0.20.4, and the current beta version is 1.0.0-beta.29. Can you clarify what you're using?

Comment: If I floor the result, it will need to be at least above one so gas price is not 0.  npm -v web3 returns 5.6.0 | npm list web3 returns  web3@1.0.0-beta.29

Comment: Fractions of wei don't exist, so if your gas price has to be less than 1 wei, you have no choice but to set it to 0 wei.

Comment: Something very strange is going on if that's really the code you're running. Perhaps it's a bug in the node you're connecting to? Are you connected to geth? Parity? Infura? ganache? Something else?

Comment: (FYI, 5.6.0 is the version of `npm` you're using.)

Comment: That means that the address would need to have minimum 130091 * 1000000000 Wei = 0.000130091 ETH in order to do the transaction, am I correct? Also I'm connected to infura

Comment: No, it would have to have a minimum of 130091 wei, which is 0.000000000000130091 ether. (130091 / 130091 == 1)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, I'm going crazy with all the unit conversion

Comment: I'm suspicious of your code, since the output you pasted doesn't match the log messages. I'll repeat that `web3.eth.getBalance` gives you the balance in wei. If you're seeing something different, you'll have to give some compelling evidence (e.g. a minimal repro that anyone can run pointing to a mainnet node that returns the wrong result).

Comment: I just ran it with the math floor and got the following output: https://comp.st/i70w   - the code in the paste is basically the code I'm using, I had just removed the console.logs to remove noise but thats it

Comment: It's hard to believe that, given that the code is doing something bizarre and the `console.log` lines don't match the output.

Comment: Please just run `web3.eth.getBalance('0x<your address here>').then(console.log);`

Comment: And please answer my question of what node you're connected to.

Comment: I said it above, I'm on infura network. Also turns out I'm retarded, I forgot to include the following line in the source `var balance = web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether');` .

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that you said you were on Infura. Ah, that line explains how you got ether instead of wei. That's why I insisted on seeing the actual code. :-) See my most recent edit for what I think the remaining issue is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense, but where should I specify the amount of tokens I want to transfer?

Comment: nevermind, I just realized that goes in the data part

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73168/discussion-on-answer-by-smarx-use-full-ethereum-balance-for-token-transaction).